# ScreenVisibilityListener in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using the code below to register to know the changes of the screens.
Problem when I use SharedElementTransition. to push on a screen. It does not fire the event that was logged.
Has anyone ever experienced this?

version:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.47.1
react-native-navigation:1.1.256

Register event screen:

```
export const registerScreenVisibilityListener = (store) => {
  new ScreenVisibilityListener({
    willAppear: ({screen}) => console.log(`Screen will disappear ${screen}`),
    didAppear: ({screen}) => console.log(`Screen will disappear ${screen}`),
    willDisappear: ({screen}) => console.log(`Screen will disappear ${screen}`),
    didDisappear: ({screen}) => console.log(`Screen disappeared ${screen}`)
  }).register();
}
```

push screen:

```
navigator.push({
    screen: 'Test',
    sharedElements: [`image`],
    animationType: 'slide-horizontal',
    navigatorStyle
});
```